# Markers along a route in HERE Maps, RouteBoxer port

Tags: here-api

I am looking to get this:

[image]

When I used Google Maps API there was a "plugin" called RouteBoxer that created a grid along the route and after I could build a query using the bounds of each rectangle.

I have seen that there is a port of that Google Library for LeafLet but I haven't found a port of RouteBoxer library for HERE Maps.

Do exist another way to do that in HERE Maps?

Extended explanation of routeboxer way: [how it works](http://194.190.129.43/hughes/static/gmaps-utility-library-dev/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html)

Thank you,

Regards,

WIP EDIT: I'm porting the Google Library by myself. I almost get it but left calculate box intersections correctly...I am here just right now:

[image]

Comment: Trying to understand what do you need in fine. In the picture, do the markers along the route represent the result of a query for places? If so, the Search Places API from HERE can be provided a `route` parameter describing the route, and the width of it, along which the places are searched. Or you're looking to achieve something else?

Comment: Hi! markers are result of a query to my database not Places API, is for that I need an implementation like google RouteBoxer. Now I am stuck because H.geo.Rect is  similar google.maps.LatLngBounds but not same and my class isn't calculate correctly the intersections but looks good.

Comment: I see. Just an idea, if the port of RouteBoxer doesn't give expected results. Maybe something like http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon could help? This works on geoJSON, so it assumes some transformation of course. It also assumes transforming the route representation into a polygon, so not sure it's much faster to get there than the RouteBoxer port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have ported by myself the original Google Routeboxer library to Here Maps v3 3.0 successfully.

- Result:

[image]

- Tips for classes:

google.maps.LatLngBounds is similar to H.geo.Rect

google.maps.LatLng       is similar to H.geo.Point

- Tips for methods:

google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend is similar to H.geo.Rect.mergeLatLng

- New methods prototyped for H.geo.Rect:

getNorthEast() and getSouthWest()

Usage:

Include here-routeboxer.js after Here Maps JS api call and:

```
// after recieve route response
var route = result.response.route[0];
var path = route.shape;

var path_= [];

// Transform original path to an array of H.geo.Point
// TODO: create a simplified path for better perfomance
path.forEach(function(point) {
    var parts = point.split(',');
    path_.push(new H.geo.Point(parts[0], parts[1]));
});

var routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();
var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path_, 3); // params: path and distance

// now use the boxes as you want :)
```

here-routeboxer.js:

```
/**
 * @name Here-RouteBoxer
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * based on
 *
 * @name RouteBoxer
 * @version 1.0
 * @copyright (c) 2010 Google Inc.
 * @author Thor Mitchell
 *
 * @fileoverview The RouteBoxer class takes a path, such as the Polyline for a
 * route generated by a Directions request, and generates a set of LatLngBounds
 * objects that are guaranteed to contain every point within a given distance
 * of that route. These LatLngBounds objects can then be used to generate
 * requests to spatial search services that support bounds filtering (such as
 * the Google Maps Data API) in order to implement search along a route.
 * <br/><br/>
 * RouteBoxer overlays a grid of the specified size on the route, identifies
 * every grid cell that the route passes through, and generates a set of bounds
 * that cover all of these cells, and their nearest neighbours. Consequently
 * the bounds returned will extend up to ~3x the specified distance from the
 * route in places.
 */

/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License. 
 */

/**
 * Creates a new RouteBoxer
 *
 * @constructor
 */
function RouteBoxer() {
  this.R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
}

/**
 * Generates boxes for a given route and distance
 *
 * @param {google.maps.LatLng[] | google.maps.Polyline} path The path along
 *           which to create boxes. The path object can be either an Array of
 *           google.maps.LatLng objects or a Maps API v2 or Maps API v3
 *           google.maps.Polyline object.
 * @param {Number} range The distance in kms around the route that the generated
 *           boxes must cover.
 * @return {google.maps.LatLngBounds[]} An array of boxes that covers the whole
 *           path.
 */
RouteBoxer.prototype.box = function (path, range) {
  // Two dimensional array representing the cells in the grid overlaid on the path
  this.grid_ = null;

  // Array that holds the latitude coordinate of each vertical grid line
  this.latGrid_ = [];

  // Array that holds the longitude coordinate of each horizontal grid line  
  this.lngGrid_ = [];

  // Array of bounds that cover the whole route formed by merging cells that
  //  the route intersects first horizontally, and then vertically
  this.boxesX_ = [];

  // Array of bounds that cover the whole route formed by merging cells that
  //  the route intersects first vertically, and then horizontally
  this.boxesY_ = [];

  // The array of LatLngs representing the vertices of the path
  var vertices = null;

  // If necessary convert the path into an array of LatLng objects
  if (path instanceof Array) {
    // already an arry of LatLngs (eg. v3 overview_path)
    vertices = path;   
  }

  // Build the grid that is overlaid on the route
  this.buildGrid_(vertices, range);

  // Identify the grid cells that the route intersects
  this.findIntersectingCells_(vertices);

  // Merge adjacent intersected grid cells (and their neighbours) into two sets
  //  of bounds, both of which cover them completely
  this.mergeIntersectingCells_();

  // Return the set of merged bounds that has the fewest elements
  return (this.boxesX_.length <= this.boxesY_.length ?
          this.boxesX_ :
          this.boxesY_);
};

/**
 * Generates boxes for a given route and distance
 *
 * @param {LatLng[]} vertices The vertices of the path over which to lay the grid
 * @param {Number} range The spacing of the grid cells.
 */
RouteBoxer.prototype.buildGrid_ = function (vertices, range) {

  // Create a LatLngBounds object that contains the whole path
  // var routeBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var routeBounds = new H.geo.Rect(vertices[0].lat, vertices[0].lng, vertices[0].lat, vertices[0].lng);
  // alert(vertices.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    routeBounds = routeBounds.mergeLatLng(vertices[i].lat, vertices[i].lng);     
  }

  // Find the center of the bounding box of the path
  var routeBoundsCenter = routeBounds.getCenter();

  // Starting from the center define grid lines outwards vertically until they
  //  extend beyond the edge of the bounding box by more than one cell
  this.latGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.lat);

  // Add lines from the center out to the north
  this.latGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(0, range).lat);
  for (i = 2; this.latGrid_[i - 2] < routeBounds.getNorthEast().lat; i++) {
    this.latGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(0, range * i).lat);
  }

  // Add lines from the center out to the south  
  for (i = 1; this.latGrid_[1] > routeBounds.getSouthWest().lat; i++) {
    this.latGrid_.unshift(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(180, range * i).lat);
  }

  // Starting from the center define grid lines outwards horizontally until they
  //  extend beyond the edge of the bounding box by more than one cell  
  this.lngGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.lng);

  // Add lines from the center out to the east
  this.lngGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(90, range).lng);
  for (i = 2; this.lngGrid_[i - 2] < routeBounds.getNorthEast().lng; i++) {
    this.lngGrid_.push(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(90, range * i).lng);
  }

  // Add lines from the center out to the west
  for (i = 1; this.lngGrid_[1] > routeBounds.getSouthWest().lng; i++) {
    this.lngGrid_.unshift(routeBoundsCenter.rhumbDestinationPoint(270, range * i).lng);
  }

  // Create a two dimensional array representing this grid
  this.grid_ = new Array(this.lngGrid_.length);
  for (i = 0; i < this.grid_.length; i++) {
    this.grid_[i] = new Array(this.latGrid_.length);
  }
};

H.geo.Rect.prototype.getNorthEast = function () {
  return new H.geo.Point(this.getTop(), this.getRight());
};

H.geo.Rect.prototype.getSouthWest = function () {
  return new H.geo.Point(this.getBottom(), this.getLeft());
};

/**
 * Find all of the cells in the overlaid grid that the path intersects
 *
 * @param {LatLng[]} vertices The vertices of the path
 */
RouteBoxer.prototype.findIntersectingCells_ = function (vertices) {
  // Find the cell where the path begins
  var hintXY = this.getCellCoords_(vertices[0]);

  // Mark that cell and it's neighbours for inclusion in the boxes
  this.markCell_(hintXY);

  // Work through each vertex on the path identifying which grid cell it is in
  for (var i = 1; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    // Use the known cell of the previous vertex to help find the cell of this vertex
    var gridXY = this.getGridCoordsFromHint_(vertices[i], vertices[i - 1], hintXY);

    if (gridXY[0] === hintXY[0] && gridXY[1] === hintXY[1]) {
      // This vertex is in the same cell as the previous vertex
      // The cell will already have been marked for inclusion in the boxes
      continue;

    } else if ((Math.abs(hintXY[0] - gridXY[0]) === 1 && hintXY[1] === gridXY[1]) ||
        (hintXY[0] === gridXY[0] && Math.abs(hintXY[1] - gridXY[1]) === 1)) {
      // This vertex is in a cell that shares an edge with the previous cell
      // Mark this cell and it's neighbours for inclusion in the boxes
      this.markCell_(gridXY);

    } else {
      // This vertex is in a cell that does not share an edge with the previous
      //  cell. This means that the path passes through other cells between
      //  this vertex and the previous vertex, and we must determine which cells
      //  it passes through
      this.getGridIntersects_(vertices[i - 1], vertices[i], hintXY, gridXY);
    }

    // Use this cell to find and compare with the next one
    hintXY = gridXY;
  }
};

/**
 * Find the cell a path vertex is in by brute force iteration over the grid
 *
 * @param {LatLng[]} latlng The latlng of the vertex
 * @return {Number[][]} The cell coordinates of this vertex in the grid
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.getCellCoords_ = function (latlng) {
  for (var x = 0; this.lngGrid_[x] < latlng.lng; x++) {}
  for (var y = 0; this.latGrid_[y] < latlng.lat; y++) {}
  return ([x - 1, y - 1]);
};

/**
 * Find the cell a path vertex is in based on the known location of a nearby
 *  vertex. This saves searching the whole grid when working through vertices
 *  on the polyline that are likely to be in close proximity to each other.
 *
 * @param {LatLng[]} latlng The latlng of the vertex to locate in the grid
 * @param {LatLng[]} hintlatlng The latlng of the vertex with a known location
 * @param {Number[]} hint The cell containing the vertex with a known location
 * @return {Number[]} The cell coordinates of the vertex to locate in the grid
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.getGridCoordsFromHint_ = function (latlng, hintlatlng, hint) {
  var x, y;
  if (latlng.lng > hintlatlng.lng) {
    for (x = hint[0]; this.lngGrid_[x + 1] < latlng.lng; x++) {}
  } else {
    for (x = hint[0]; this.lngGrid_[x] > latlng.lng; x--) {}
  }

  if (latlng.lat > hintlatlng.lat) {
    for (y = hint[1]; this.latGrid_[y + 1] < latlng.lat; y++) {}
  } else {        
    for (y = hint[1]; this.latGrid_[y] > latlng.lat; y--) {}
  }

  return ([x, y]);
};


/**
 * Identify the grid squares that a path segment between two vertices
 * intersects with by:
 * 1. Finding the bearing between the start and end of the segment
 * 2. Using the delta between the lat of the start and the lat of each
 *    latGrid boundary to find the distance to each latGrid boundary
 * 3. Finding the lng of the intersection of the line with each latGrid
 *     boundary using the distance to the intersection and bearing of the line
 * 4. Determining the x-coord on the grid of the point of intersection
 * 5. Filling in all squares between the x-coord of the previous intersection
 *     (or start) and the current one (or end) at the current y coordinate,
 *     which is known for the grid line being intersected
 *     
 * @param {LatLng} start The latlng of the vertex at the start of the segment
 * @param {LatLng} end The latlng of the vertex at the end of the segment
 * @param {Number[]} startXY The cell containing the start vertex
 * @param {Number[]} endXY The cell containing the vend vertex
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.getGridIntersects_ = function (start, end, startXY, endXY) {
  var edgePoint, edgeXY, i;
  var brng = start.rhumbBearingTo(end);         // Step 1.

  var hint = start;
  var hintXY = startXY;

  // Handle a line segment that travels south first
  if (end.lat > start.lat) {
    // Iterate over the east to west grid lines between the start and end cells
    for (i = startXY[1] + 1; i <= endXY[1]; i++) {
      // Find the latlng of the point where the path segment intersects with
      //  this grid line (Step 2 & 3)
      edgePoint = this.getGridIntersect_(start, brng, this.latGrid_[i]);

      // Find the cell containing this intersect point (Step 4)
      edgeXY = this.getGridCoordsFromHint_(edgePoint, hint, hintXY);

      // Mark every cell the path has crossed between this grid and the start,
      //   or the previous east to west grid line it crossed (Step 5)
      this.fillInGridSquares_(hintXY[0], edgeXY[0], i - 1);

      // Use the point where it crossed this grid line as the reference for the
      //  next iteration
      hint = edgePoint;
      hintXY = edgeXY;
    }

    // Mark every cell the path has crossed between the last east to west grid
    //  line it crossed and the end (Step 5)
    this.fillInGridSquares_(hintXY[0], endXY[0], i - 1);

  } else {
    // Iterate over the east to west grid lines between the start and end cells
    for (i = startXY[1]; i > endXY[1]; i--) {
      // Find the latlng of the point where the path segment intersects with
      //  this grid line (Step 2 & 3)
      edgePoint = this.getGridIntersect_(start, brng, this.latGrid_[i]);

      // Find the cell containing this intersect point (Step 4)
      edgeXY = this.getGridCoordsFromHint_(edgePoint, hint, hintXY);

      // Mark every cell the path has crossed between this grid and the start,
      //   or the previous east to west grid line it crossed (Step 5)
      this.fillInGridSquares_(hintXY[0], edgeXY[0], i);

      // Use the point where it crossed this grid line as the reference for the
      //  next iteration
      hint = edgePoint;
      hintXY = edgeXY;
    }

    // Mark every cell the path has crossed between the last east to west grid
    //  line it crossed and the end (Step 5)
    this.fillInGridSquares_(hintXY[0], endXY[0], i);

  }
};

/**
 * Find the latlng at which a path segment intersects with a given
 *   line of latitude
 *     
 * @param {LatLng} start The vertex at the start of the path segment
 * @param {Number} brng The bearing of the line from start to end
 * @param {Number} gridLineLat The latitude of the grid line being intersected
 * @return {LatLng} The latlng of the point where the path segment intersects
 *                    the grid line
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.getGridIntersect_ = function (start, brng, gridLineLat) {
  var d = this.R * ((gridLineLat.toRad() - start.lat.toRad()) / Math.cos(brng.toRad()));
  return start.rhumbDestinationPoint(brng, d);
};

/**
 * Mark all cells in a given row of the grid that lie between two columns
 *   for inclusion in the boxes
 *     
 * @param {Number} startx The first column to include
 * @param {Number} endx The last column to include
 * @param {Number} y The row of the cells to include
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.fillInGridSquares_ = function (startx, endx, y) {
  var x;
  if (startx < endx) {
    for (x = startx; x <= endx; x++) {
      this.markCell_([x, y]);
    }
  } else {
    for (x = startx; x >= endx; x--) {
      this.markCell_([x, y]);
    }            
  }      
};

/**
 * Mark a cell and the 8 immediate neighbours for inclusion in the boxes
 *     
 * @param {Number[]} square The cell to mark
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.markCell_ = function (cell) {
  var x = cell[0];
  var y = cell[1];
  this.grid_[x - 1][y - 1] = 1;
  this.grid_[x][y - 1] = 1;
  this.grid_[x + 1][y - 1] = 1;
  this.grid_[x - 1][y] = 1;
  this.grid_[x][y] = 1;
  this.grid_[x + 1][y] = 1;
  this.grid_[x - 1][y + 1] = 1;
  this.grid_[x][y + 1] = 1;
  this.grid_[x + 1][y + 1] = 1;
};

/**
 * Create two sets of bounding boxes, both of which cover all of the cells that
 *   have been marked for inclusion.
 *
 * The first set is created by combining adjacent cells in the same column into
 *   a set of vertical rectangular boxes, and then combining boxes of the same
 *   height that are adjacent horizontally.
 *
 * The second set is created by combining adjacent cells in the same row into
 *   a set of horizontal rectangular boxes, and then combining boxes of the same
 *   width that are adjacent vertically.
 *     
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.mergeIntersectingCells_ = function () {
  var x, y, box;

  // The box we are currently expanding with new cells
  var currentBox = null;

  // Traverse the grid a row at a time
  for (y = 0; y < this.grid_[0].length; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < this.grid_.length; x++) {

      if (this.grid_[x][y]) {
        // This cell is marked for inclusion. If the previous cell in this
        //   row was also marked for inclusion, merge this cell into it's box.
        // Otherwise start a new box.
        box = this.getCellBounds_([x, y]);

        if (currentBox) {
          currentBox = currentBox.mergeLatLng(box.getNorthEast().lat, box.getNorthEast().lng);
        } else {
          currentBox = box;
        }

      } else {
        // This cell is not marked for inclusion. If the previous cell was
        //  marked for inclusion, merge it's box with a box that spans the same
        //  columns from the row below if possible.
        this.mergeBoxesY_(currentBox);
        currentBox = null;
      }
    }
    // If the last cell was marked for inclusion, merge it's box with a matching
    //  box from the row below if possible.
    this.mergeBoxesY_(currentBox);
    currentBox = null;
  }

  // Traverse the grid a column at a time
  for (x = 0; x < this.grid_.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < this.grid_[0].length; y++) {
      if (this.grid_[x][y]) {

        // This cell is marked for inclusion. If the previous cell in this
        //   column was also marked for inclusion, merge this cell into it's box.
        // Otherwise start a new box.
        if (currentBox) {
          box = this.getCellBounds_([x, y]);
          currentBox = currentBox.mergeLatLng(box.getNorthEast().lat, box.getNorthEast().lng);
        } else {
          currentBox = this.getCellBounds_([x, y]);
        }

      } else {
        // This cell is not marked for inclusion. If the previous cell was
        //  marked for inclusion, merge it's box with a box that spans the same
        //  rows from the column to the left if possible.
        this.mergeBoxesX_(currentBox);
        currentBox = null;

      }
    }
    // If the last cell was marked for inclusion, merge it's box with a matching
    //  box from the column to the left if possible.
    this.mergeBoxesX_(currentBox);
    currentBox = null;
  }
};

/**
 * Search for an existing box in an adjacent row to the given box that spans the
 * same set of columns and if one is found merge the given box into it. If one
 * is not found, append this box to the list of existing boxes.
 *
 * @param {LatLngBounds}  The box to merge
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.mergeBoxesX_ = function (box) {
  if (box !== null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.boxesX_.length; i++) {
      if (this.boxesX_[i].getNorthEast().lng === box.getSouthWest().lng &&
          this.boxesX_[i].getSouthWest().lat === box.getSouthWest().lat &&
          this.boxesX_[i].getNorthEast().lat === box.getNorthEast().lat) {
        this.boxesX_[i] = this.boxesX_[i].mergeLatLng(box.getNorthEast().lat, box.getNorthEast().lng);
        return;
      }
    }
    this.boxesX_.push(box);
  }
};

/**
 * Search for an existing box in an adjacent column to the given box that spans
 * the same set of rows and if one is found merge the given box into it. If one
 * is not found, append this box to the list of existing boxes.
 *
 * @param {LatLngBounds}  The box to merge
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.mergeBoxesY_ = function (box) {
  if (box !== null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.boxesY_.length; i++) {
      if (this.boxesY_[i].getNorthEast().lat === box.getSouthWest().lat &&
          this.boxesY_[i].getSouthWest().lng === box.getSouthWest().lng &&
          this.boxesY_[i].getNorthEast().lng === box.getNorthEast().lng) {
        this.boxesY_[i] = this.boxesY_[i].mergeLatLng(box.getNorthEast().lat, box.getNorthEast().lng);
        return;
      }
    }
    this.boxesY_.push(box);
  }
};

/**
 * Obtain the LatLng of the origin of a cell on the grid
 *
 * @param {Number[]} cell The cell to lookup.
 * @return {LatLng} The latlng of the origin of the cell.
 */ 
RouteBoxer.prototype.getCellBounds_ = function (cell) {
  return new H.geo.Rect(this.latGrid_[cell[1]+1], this.lngGrid_[cell[0]],this.latGrid_[cell[1]], this.lngGrid_[cell[0] + 1]);
};

/* Based on the Latitude/longitude spherical geodesy formulae & scripts
   at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
   (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010
*/ 
H.geo.Point.prototype.rhumbDestinationPoint = function (brng, dist) {
  var R = 6371; // earth's mean radius in km
  var d = parseFloat(dist) / R;  // d = angular distance covered on earth's surface
  var lat1 = this.lat.toRad(), lon1 = this.lng.toRad();
  brng = brng.toRad();

  var lat2 = lat1 + d * Math.cos(brng);
  var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
  var dPhi = Math.log(Math.tan(lat2 / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(lat1 / 2 + Math.PI / 4));
  var q = (Math.abs(dLat) > 1e-10) ? dLat / dPhi : Math.cos(lat1);
  var dLon = d * Math.sin(brng) / q;
  // check for going past the pole
  if (Math.abs(lat2) > Math.PI / 2) {
    lat2 = lat2 > 0 ? Math.PI - lat2 : - (Math.PI - lat2);
  }
  var lon2 = (lon1 + dLon + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;

  if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) {
    return null;
  }
  return new H.geo.Point(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
};

H.geo.Point.prototype.rhumbBearingTo = function (dest) {
  var dLon = (dest.lng - this.lng).toRad();
  var dPhi = Math.log(Math.tan(dest.lat.toRad() / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(this.lat.toRad() / 2 + Math.PI / 4));
  if (Math.abs(dLon) > Math.PI) {
    dLon = dLon > 0 ? -(2 * Math.PI - dLon) : (2 * Math.PI + dLon);
  }
  return Math.atan2(dLon, dPhi).toBrng();
};

/**
 * Extend the Number object to convert degrees to radians
 *
 * @return {Number} Bearing in radians
 * @ignore
 */ 
Number.prototype.toRad = function () {
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
};

/**
 * Extend the Number object to convert radians to degrees
 *
 * @return {Number} Bearing in degrees
 * @ignore
 */ 
Number.prototype.toDeg = function () {
  return this * 180 / Math.PI;
};

/**
 * Normalize a heading in degrees to between 0 and +360
 *
 * @return {Number} Return 
 * @ignore
 */ 
Number.prototype.toBrng = function () {
  return (this.toDeg() + 360) % 360;
};
```